# fatal error: string: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, cmake, g++

I get this message upon compiling with cmake:

```
In file included from scanner.lex:6:
C:\Users\uriya\CLionProjects\untitled1\output.hpp:4:10: fatal error: string: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <string>
      |          ^~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\untitled1.dir\build.make:88: CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/lex.yy.c.obj] Error 1
make.exe[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:72: CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/all] Error 2
make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:84: CMakeFiles/untitled1.dir/rule] Error 2
make.exe: *** [Makefile:117: untitled1] Error 2
```

This is the part of the code that causes the problems:

```
#ifndef _236360_2_
#define _236360_2_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

namespace output {
    extern const string rules[];
    void printProductionRule(int ruleno);
    void errorLex(int lineno);
    void errorSyn(int lineno);
};

#endif
```

and that's the cmake input:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(untitled1)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_executable(untitled1 parser.tab.cpp output.cpp lex.yy.c)
```

oddly enough I manage to compile it with no problems using `g++ -std=c++11 -o hw2 parser.tab.cpp output.cpp lex.yy.c`
what's the difference between cmake and this command?

Comment: Is scanner.lex being compiled as C or C++?

Comment: Maybe I don't know something, But I thought everything is compiled automatically as c++. How can I choose what to compile it as?

Comment: "How can I choose what to compile it as?" - You choose a compiler by using **proper extension** of source file. `.c` is extensions for C source. If file `lex.yy.c` contains C++ code, then its extension is wrong.

Comment: It only contains C code, but somehow this actually worked for me!
Thank you for your help!

Comment: If it only contains c why are you including the c++ header `string`?

Comment: @Uriyasama Btw: you can overwrite the language of a source file regardless of it's extension; you just need to set the correct source file property: `set_source_files_properties(lex.yy.c PROPERTIES LANGUAGE CXX)`